# Miss colorout library (Installing rCharts)

Tags: r, rcharts

I am installing rcharts library for my R, version 3.5.0.

I have previously sucessfully installed rcharts for version 3.4. 
But I redo operations for R 3.5.0 and it is buggy.

I download https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts, load the devtools, Rcpp, RCurl, RJSONIO libraries. Finally I install:

install.packages ("C: / rchartsdownload", repos = NULL, type = "source")

And this is the result I got

```
============================================================

Configuration CDC :

    Proxy :
        HTTP  = pxy-http-srv:8080
        HTTPS = pxy-http-srv:8080

    Serveur de paquets (le seul accessible via le proxy) :
        https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/

    Librairie locale de paquets : 
        C:\Developpement\R_Packages\

    Fichiers de config pris en compte :
        C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0\Renviron.site
        C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0\Rprofile.site
Error in library("colorout") : 
  no package named 'colorout' is found
Stopped execution
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/rchartsdownload’ had non-zero exit status
```

It looks like it's missing colorout library. However, I learned that this library was deleted and no longer exists on R. So how do I fix this?

Hope to hear back from you soon,

Thank you very much

Comment: install from GitHub: https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout

Comment: Thank you! But I have to work on window. In the link you send me, it noitice that "colorout is an R package that colorizes R output when running in a Unix terminal (eg Linux and OS X) terminal emulator; it does not work on Microsoft Windows."

Is there a solution in this case?

Comment: I installed the `rCharts` successfully on Linux and Windows (R 3.5.0) using `devtools::install_github("ramnathv/rCharts")`. `colourout` was not required ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the package by starting R with `R --vanilla` and then running `install.packages(..)` (or respectively `install_github(..)`). I assume you might have a `~/.Rprofile` command which tries to load `colourout`